# Is event.which deprecated in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, deprecated

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent) event.which is obsolete however in [jQuery documentation](https://api.jquery.com/event.which/) it isn't marked as deprecated. Do I understand it correctly that it's deprecated only in plain JS and in jQuery it's still OK to use it?

Comment: jQuery Event is not exactly the JS's native Event. If you want to get the native event in jQuery you use `jQEvent.originalEvent` So, `jQEvent.which` is just way jQuery handles a  crossbrowser normalization. Could have been called "key" but they went for "which"